# CI Dropdown Select

Tags: php, codeigniter

Anyone know why with the following code I'm getting this error message. I'm trying to have it shows the data from my array as each option will have a value of the user's id and the text for the option will be their name. As of right now it only shows the last person.

> A PHP Error was encountered
>
> Severity: Warning
>
> Message: Illegal offset type in isset or empty
>
> Filename: helpers/form_helper.php
>
> Line Number: 319

```
<?php echo form_label('Recipient', 'recipient'); ?>

<?php 

$data = array(
    'name'   => 'to',
    'class'  => 'required'
);

foreach($users AS $user)
{
    $options = array (
        $user->user_id => $user->first_name.' '.$user->last_name
    );     
}   
?>

<?php echo form_dropdown($data, $options); ?>
```

UDPATE:

```
<?php echo form_label('Recipient', 'recipient'); ?>

<?php 

$data = array(
    'name'   => 'to',
    'class'  => 'required'
);

$options = array();

foreach($users AS $user)
{
    $options[] = array (
        $user->user_id => $user->first_name.' '.$user->last_name
    );

    $options[] = $user; 
}   
?>

<?php echo form_dropdown($data, $options); ?>
```

Any other ideas?

Comment: One note: the `$options` array you've shown is being reinstantiated each time through your loop. That means it will only contain the last `$user` in `$users` by the time you try to call `form_dropdown` on it.

Comment: @rjz so how do i fix that issue.

Comment: Where is the code at line 319?

Comment: @user1244239 Shot in the dark but `form_dropdown()` is probably expecting an options array. So you want to append to `$options`, not replace it. Try `$options[] = array(...'`

Comment: Declare `$options = array()` outside your `foreach` and append each `$user` inside the loop using `$options[] = $user`.

Comment: @MikeB, it's still _technically_ an associative array with just one user in it...just a pretty lonely one :^)

Comment: @MikeB and @ rjz is this what your suggesting look at my update

Comment: Because with this I'm still getting that error message plus this Message: Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string

Comment: @user1244239 Walk me through what you think both those `$options[]` calls are doing.

Comment: I was hoping that it is adding a the user id and the users name to the options array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the line `$options[] = $user;` from your `foreach`.  `form_dropdown` expects an array with the value as the key and the text as the value.

EDIT: `$options` needs to be a 1D array (not a 2D array).

```
$options = array();

foreach($users AS $user)
{
    $options[$user->user_id] = $user->first_name.' '.$user->last_name;
}
```

EDIT 2:

```
$options = array(-1 => 'Select an option'); // Start with a "default option"

foreach($users AS $user)
{
    $options[$user->user_id] = $user->first_name.' '.$user->last_name;
}

form_dropdown('to', $options, -1, 'class="required"'); // Make the default "selected"
```

Comment: only problem with that is http://jsfiddle.net/Z47m9/. Notice its showing a 0 and 1 next to the name which is not the user_id but when I post the form it shows the right user_id

Comment: @user1244239: Huh?  What's the problem?  Where's this 0 and 1 you're talking about?

Comment: click the dropdown inside of the compose new message and notice how it shows a 0 and 1 for each user

Comment: However one last issue with it. Can I apply a class as a third parameter to the form dropdown so that i can make it required.

Comment: @user1244239: That would be the 4th parameter.  `form_dropdown('to', $options, '', 'class="required"');`

Comment: How would I add an option to the top of the dropdown that it says please select an option and that its the default option and has a empty value

Comment: That way if that option is still selected when the user submits the form it will throw the error message.

Answer (score 2):

From the documentation: http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/form_helper.html

> **The first parameter will contain the name of the field**, the second parameter will contain an associative array of options, and the third parameter will contain the value you wish to be selected.

You're passing an associative array, and it's expecting a string.